# QTableView problems with row

Tags: qt, row, qtableview

Hello guys i new to QT and i am doing Qtableview to add information in 3 columns to infinite row like

```
|--1--|--2--|--3--|

|--1--|--2--|--3--|

|--1--|--2--|--3--|
```

this is how i want to insert/append row but this is how i am getting after insert/append row functions.

```
|--1--|--2--|--3--|

|-----|-----|-----||--1--|--2--|--3--|

|-----|-----|-----||-----|-----|-----||--1--|--2--|--3--|
```

i am getting empty gaps and increased column count

i am using `QStandardItemmodel` for model this is code that creates the model item

```
void tableview::add_tableview() //this is used to add data to tableview
{
    //to get data from line edit in add window
    QStandardItem *item_1 = new QStandardItem(QString(enter1_edit->text()));
    QStandardItem *item_2 = new QStandardItem(QString(enter2_edit->text()));
    QStandardItem *item_3 = new QStandardItem(QString(enter3_edit->text()));

     list << item_1 << item_2 << item_3;

     model->appendRow(list);

    //to set the model
    main_tableview->setModel(model);
}
```

The values in the rows are added using `qlineedit enter1_edit,enter2_edit & enter3_edit`(its in other function/method)

`main_tableview` is the object of `qtableview`

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I think you need to give some more information: what is `list`? Do you clear it after using it each time? What do you mean regarding `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 0):

Ding Ding Ding, I have it.
I tried to reproduce your problem without success unil I tried something...suboptimal :).
Is your `list` by any chance a global entity? If yes (and I assume it is) you keep adding items to it.

First time you call `add_tableview()` all is good, `list` is empty, gets three `QStandardItem` pointers added and is used to append a row with those three items. So far so god.

You call `add_tableview()` again, now you create another three `QStandardItem`s and APPEND them to the list (which still contains the three from the last call). Invoking `appendRow()` actually tries to insert six items, from which the first three allready exist in the model. And as you know you mustn't add the same item pointer to a model twice. Thankfully Qt doesn't crash but inserts three empty columns for the item pointers allready in it.

Solution: At the end of your `add_tableview()` method call `list.clear()` or use a local variable for the list. The overhead should be minimal.

Best regards
D